# Confused about namespaces and istio gateways

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm confused about the practicality of k8s namespaces and istio gateways.

Let's say that I have a cluster that runs the workloads of 3 teams. Each team has a deployment that deploys an API. The API looks like:

`https://dev.mydomain.com/APIs/teamName`

I want to create a namespace per team, so that all the workloads belonging to a team will end up in their own namespace.

How do I configure the istio gateway?!

For my understanding I need an istio gateway per namespace, but how k8s knows which gateway needs to be used since the host is the same for all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ensuring all the workloads belong to a team,you can create `3 different namespaces` and deploy each workload in 3 different namespaces.

Let’s say I have created `3 namespaces`:(I Am using `GCP console`)

```
@cloudshell:~ $ kubectl create namespace team-a
namespace/team-a created
@cloudshell:~$ kubectl create namespace team-b
namespace/team-b created
@cloudshell:~$ kubectl create namespace team-c
namespace/team-c created
```

Deployed the workloads in `3 namespaces`:

[image]

So you will be having `3 API’s`, Now create a istio gateway.

Instead of creating a istio gateway you can create `3 virtual services` where a `single Istio Gateway` has the host [dev.mydomain.com](http://dev.mydomain.com) and routes the traffic to different VirtualServices based on the URL path. So try creating a virtual service for each team’s API.

Attaching [best practices document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#split-virtual-services) for more information.

**Edit :**

As per this [blog](https://dbones.github.io/2020/07/istio-gateway-in-a-different-namespace/) by Dave,  reference the gateway using a namespace/gateway-name syntax in virtual service

Comment: When I tried this on my test cluster, the connection to my pod didn't work, and it only worked after I updated the namespace of my gateway and virtual service to match the namespace of the pod. I'll try tomorrow, but if I understand this correctly, you are saying that I can deploy a single gateway in any of the namespaces and the traffic will flow as long as the namespace of the virtual service matches the one of my pod. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes you need to match the namespace of the virtual service and pod.

Comment: I just tried and this didn't work. If I remove the namespace on the gateway, the traffic no longer flows to my virtual service.

Comment: Update: I found this page here: http://dbones.github.io/2020/07/istio-gateway-in-a-different-namespace/

Of course, I needed to reference  the gateway using a `namespace/gateway-name syntax` in my virtual service!

Comment: Great that resolved the issue adding the link in answer for community members.